# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS not showing up in boot menu, Windows 8

Tags: windows

I have Ubuntu on a flash drive and when I try to boot it my only option is the windows boot manager.

Answer (score 0):

If it is on a flash drive you need to press f12 (or your computer's equivalent) and select the usb to boot from it. Overall that is the easiest solution, as even just dual-booting normally with windows 8 has been a pain for a great many people.

Comment: That's what I have been doing, but I only have one option (boot windows) when I press F12.  I have tried holding shift and editing some boot settings but nothing is seeming to work.

Comment: oh right, because of uefi and everything. Are you sure the bootloader is installed to the usb?

Comment: Yes.  I tried to re-install it too.

Comment: I need to look up a few things but I'll get back to you

Comment: Secure boot is disabled, fast boot is enabled, usb boot is enabled, and boot mood is UEFI. Does this help at all?

Comment: disable fast boot, that will completely disable basically any other booting

Answer (score 0):

You have the boot order in your bios configuration. Check if the flash disk is activate and in the right order. If your computer is an window's 8 machine, maybe you will boot on unsecure mode to do it.

Comment: how do you check if the flash disk is active and in the right order?

Comment: enter bios configuration and go to the boot order. You will see all the activated boot media and their order

Comment: The only device that appeared was the Windows Boot Manager.  Secure boot is disabled, fast boot is enabled, usb boot is enabled, and boot mood is UEFI.  Does this help at all?

Comment: please give me the other option of boot mode and the usb boot order